# Sphinx Docs not importing Django project settings

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I just recently move a Django project into a new virtualenv. The project works fine, but I am having trouble building my Sphinx Documentation.

in my conf.py I have this:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('/path/to/myproject')

from django.core.management import setup_environ
from myproject import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

But when I use `make html` I get this error:

```
from myproject import settings
  ImportError: No module named myproject
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the conf.py needs to look like this:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('/path/to')

from myproject import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.4 deprecated `setup_environ`.  Here's similar code for Django 1.4 and later:

```py
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
parent = os.path.dirname(cwd)
sys.path.append(parent)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this problem with a Django 1.7.5 project and I think it's down to some strange project layout decisions we made, but I needed one extra step to solve this using jwhitlock's answer:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
from django.conf import settings
```

When I did that useless import it found my custom Django settings which were specified in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` but were not found by the autodoc process. I think this is because the project lives in a folder whose parent has the same name, but inspecting `sys.path` only shows the "right" folder so the import should work but blows up saying it can't find my settings.