# documenting django project with sphinx error on import

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I'm documenting a django project of mine but got stuck with some errors when I run `make html`.

If I go to the .py file where the error is happening and comment the imports at the beginning of the file, the `make html` command runs flawlessly.

And this is part of the error message:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not
>   configured. You must either define the environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
>   settings.

I tried this [Sphinx Docs not importing Django project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583075/sphinx-docs-not-importing-django-project-settings) but nothing.

Comment: Have you tried setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm realy new to this, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I found on this on this website([link](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/03/document-your-django-projects.html)), and worked for me.

I had to include it in my conf.py file.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```